# Extract the Linux serial number without sudo

Tags: linux, serial-number

It is possible to extract the Linux serial number without using [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)?

I know it is possible to do in Windows: `wmic bios get serialnumber` and in
macOS: `system_profiler | grep "r (system)"`. Both of them do not require root privileges.

In Linux this can be used: `sudo dmidecode -s system-serial-number`, but it needs sudo. Is there another way?

Comment: "Linux serial number" probably means the BIOS serial number (from [the WMIC example](https://www.windows-commandline.com/wmic-bios-get-serial-number/)).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`dmidecode` reads this information from physical memory, using `/dev/mem`, which requires root.

The same information is also provided by the Linux kernel via [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) in a virtual directory, `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id`.

Unfortunately, someone decided that all information in that virtual directory is open to anyone for reading, just *not* the serial numbers:

```
$ ls -l /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id

-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:12 bios_date
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 14 14:59 bios_vendor
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:12 bios_version
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:12 board_asset_tag
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:12 board_name
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:12 board_serial
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 14 14:59 board_vendor
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:12 board_version
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:12 chassis_asset_tag
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:12 chassis_serial
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:12 chassis_type
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:12 chassis_vendor
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:12 chassis_version
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:12 modalias
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Nov 25 17:12 power
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 14 14:59 product_name
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Nov 25 17:12 product_serial
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Nov 14 14:59 product_uuid
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 14 14:59 product_version
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Nov 14 14:59 subsystem -> ../../../../class/dmi
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 14 14:59 sys_vendor
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 14 14:59 uevent
```

If you can install package `hal` (not installed by default on recent Ubuntu versions), this command will work for you as non-root:

```
 lshal | grep system.hardware.serial

 system.hardware.serial = '<serial_number>'  (string)
```

This works because package `hal` installs the `hald` daemon, which runs as root and collects this data, making it possible for `lshal` to read it as non-root.

Comment: How can `lshal` access to this data if it is not launched as sudo??

Comment: This package installs `hald` daemon, which runs as root and collects this data, making it possible for `lshal` to read it.

Comment: Thank you! It is a pity that this data can not be collected without root permission

Comment: hal-get-property --udi '/org/freedesktop/HAL/devices/computer' --key system.hardware.serial will get you the serial number without having to parse if that is what you want.

Comment: Instead of starting an extra daemon, you can also add a start-up-script that runs chmod to give access to that data.

Comment: _`dmidecode` reads this information from sysfs_ — does it? On my system, when I run it without root, it complains that `/dev/mem` isn't accessible.

Comment: @Ruslan: Yes, you are right - dmidecode reads directly from physical memory (using `/dev/mem`). Access to `/dev/mem` still requires root access though :( I will change my answer to reflect accurate state of affairs

Comment: What is the equivalent of `hal` in Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which does not require root privileges:

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda | grep ID_SERIAL
```

This is actually the library that lsblk, mentioned by don_crissti, leverages, but my version of lsblk does not include the option for serial.

Comment: This is the disk serial number, not the BIOS one

Answer (score 0):

Device1 name and corresponding serial number:

```
lsblk --nodeps -o name,serial
```

Output:

```
NAME SERIAL
sda  0000000012400917BA30
sdb  0000000012400917BA96
```

Add *-n* if you don't want to print the header line:

```
lsblk --nodeps -no name,serial
```

Output:

```
sda  0000000012400917BA30
sdb  0000000012400917BA96
```

Pass the device as an argument to get only the serial number of a specific device:

```
lsblk --nodeps -no serial /dev/sda
```

Output:

```
0000000012400917BA30
```

Keep in mind [lsblk](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsblk) lists information about all available (or the specified) block devices. Now, for those who do not know what that last term means:

In general, block devices are devices that store or hold data. Diskette drives, hard drives and CD-ROM drives are all block devices. But that's not a problem when using lsblk as you can simply add more columns, e.g., *type* (device type) and/or *tran* (device transport type), etc.:

```
lsblk --nodeps -no name,serial,type,tran
```

.

```
sda  0000000012400917BA30     disk sata
sdb  0000000012400917BA96     disk sata
sr0  4B583242334C453233353320 rom  usb
```

Comment: The question is about the BIOS serial number, not related to disks.